# Why isn't IIF statement TRUE part evaluating correctly when trying to format Zip codes?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a `ZipCode` field in one of my tables.

Most of the values are typical 5 digit zip codes, however some of them have a dash and an additional 4 digits. The field is set to text data type.

My issue is that I would like to preserve the leading zeroes when appropriate, but not truncate the zip codes that have the additional 4 digits at the end.

The values are currently one of the following (all text data types):

- 5429
- 34567
- 21134-8733

The expected results should be the following:

- 05429
- 34567
- 21134-8733

I have created the below query.  It is not working properly, it just returns the original value of the field.

```
UPDATE [Export file2] 
SET [Export file2].ZipCode = 
IIf(Len([Export file2].[ZipCode])<6,Format([Export file2].[ZipCode],"00000"),[Export file2].[ZipCode]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format will not format a text field, so make the value numeric first:

```
UPDATE [Export file2] SET [Export file2].ZipCode = IIf(Len([Export file2].[ZipCode])<6,Format(Val([Export file2].[ZipCode]),"00000"),[Export file2].[ZipCode]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would greatly help if you could include an example of each type of data you are working with, and the expected result for each.

Assuming I've correctly understood what you are looking to achieve, you can use the `Right` function in the following way:

```sql
UPDATE [Export file2] 
SET [Export file2].ZipCode = 
IIf
(
    Len([Export file2].[ZipCode]) < 6,
    Right("00000" & [Export file2].[ZipCode],5),
    [Export file2].[ZipCode]
)
```

Alternatively, if you also want to ensure that the 'other' type of zip codes also have the appropriate leading zeroes (assuming the value will *always* be at most 10 characters in length), perhaps the following is appropriate:

```sql
UPDATE [Export file2] 
SET [Export file2].ZipCode = 
Right("00000" & [Export file2].[ZipCode], IIf(Len([Export file2].[ZipCode]) < 6,5,10)
```

Comment: The values are currently one of the following (all text data types):

5429
34567
21134-8733

The expected results should be the following:


05429
34567
21134-8733

Comment: @Chuck0185 Thanks - I have updated your question with this additional information. My proposed solution should perform as required based on your examples.